# How can I filter SPHierarchyDataSourceControl Datasource by Content Type

Tags: document-library, content-type

I am trying to display only Document Libraries using SPTreeView control. I am providing SPHierarchyDataSourceControl with ShowDocLibChildrent = true as a datasource to spTreeView control.

But this shows all the document libraries. I want to show document libraries with specific content types only. How can filter out document libs with specific content type on SPHierarchyDataSourceControl or spTreeView?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom data provider for the treeview control and then use something like the additionalpagehead delegate control to instantiate it and set it as the datasource for the treeview.

Here is an example of creating a custom site map provider: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96461/Building-a-Custom-Site-Map-Provider

Here is an example of using the additionalpagehead control: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2010-programmatically-add-javascript-meta-tags-and-css-styles-to-the-header-of-every-page/

And all you'd need to do with the TreeView control itself is:

```
WebTreeView.DataSourceID = null;
WebTreeView.DataSource = yourcustomsource;
WebTreeView.DataBind();
```